# parentheses,curly brackets automatically remove lines after that in windows 10

Tags: windows, parentheses

My question is about how to stop parentheses,curly brackets to remove next line as  parentheses,curly brackets automatically remove lines after that in windows 10.

Comment: when I writing code and inserting (), {} it is automatically removes lines after it.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015. I have also tried this thing in notepad and issue is still there.